# With FluentUI React v9, how to change the color of the primaryText and secondaryText?

Tags: reactjs, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

With FluentUI React v9, how to change the color of the `name` and `secondaryText` for only one specific component (not globally in the theme)?

This sample sucessfully change the background to `red` but I can't find a way to change the text color:

```
const useClasses = makeStyles({
  xxx: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    color: tokens.colorNeutralForegroundInverted
  }
});

const UserPersona = () => {
  const classes = useClasses();

  return (
    <Persona
      className={classes.xxx}
      name='abc'
      secondaryText='xyz'
    />
  );
};
```

Using this works but it's probably not the best solution:

```
primaryText={<span className="text-white">{fullname}</span>}
secondaryText={<span className="text-white">{role}</span>}
```

or better

```
const textColor = `text-[color:${tokens.colorNeutralForegroundInverted}]`;

...

primaryText={<span className={textColor}>{fullname}</span>}
secondaryText={<span className={textColor}>{role}</span>}
```

How to make it works with `makeStyles` ?

Answer (score 0):

Both slots, primaryText and secondaryText, have a default color set (colorNeutralForeground1). Therefore setting the color of their parent has no effect. You need to add a class to the specific slots to overwrite that default color:

```
export const ColoredPersona = () => {
  const classes = useClasses();

  return (
    <Persona
      className={classes.xxx}
      primaryText={{ children: 'abc', className: classes.text }}
      secondaryText={{ children: 'xyz', className: classes.text }}
    />
  );
};

const useClasses = makeStyles({
  xxx: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  text: {
    color: tokens.colorNeutralForegroundInverted,
  },
});
```